# approximate $\sqrt{x+y}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, linear-approximation

How can one approximate the expression

$$\sqrt{x+y}$$

I think this can achieved by a Taylor expansion but I don't know how.

Comment: In fact, a taylor expansion can also be made with two variables. Did you look it up, for example, in Wikipedia. I think, a formula is given there.

Comment: Approximate it where, around 0?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_for_multivariate_functions

Answer (score 3):

If $x\gg |y|$, the binomial theorem gives a Taylor series $\sqrt{x}\left(1+\tfrac{y}{x}\right)^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple approximation, often used in early computers, is, if $x \ge y >0$,
$$
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
= x \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1+y^2}{x^2}}
\approx x \cdot \frac{1+y^2}{2x^2}
= \frac{x+y^2}{2x}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $x\gg y \ge 0$, then $\sqrt{x+y} = \sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+y/x} \approx \sqrt{x}(1+y/(2x)...)$